# The union (limit) of a set of sets and "potential" vs "realized" infinity

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of natural numbers.

Let $A_i$ be the set $\{0, 1, 2, ..., i\}$ of natural numbers up to $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $\{A_i | i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be set of all $A_i$.

(The set $\{A_i | i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is the set $\{A_0, A_1, A_2, ...\}$, so think of it as an increasing sequence of sets that's "moving towards" $\mathbb{N}$ but **never actually reaches it**.)

Then its union $\cup \{A_i | i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is all of $\mathbb{N}$.

I don't know how to prove this, but I know that for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $x \in A_k$, ie. every element of $\mathbb{N}$ is in $A_k$ for some $k$, meaning every element of $\mathbb{N}$ is an element of $\cup \{A_i | i \in \mathbb{N}\}$, meaning $\mathbb{N}$ is a subset of $\cup \{A_i | i \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

And by definition every element of $\cup \{A_i | i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an element of $\mathbb{N}$, so $\cup \{A_i | i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

This should "prove" that the limit $\cup \{A_i | i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of the set $\{A_i | i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is all $\mathbb{N}$, but intuitively this doesn't make any sense, for several reasons:

- All the elements of $\{A_i | i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ are finite, but their limit/union is infinite.
- No element of $\{A_i | i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is all of $\mathbb{N}$ but their union somehow, mysteriously, becomes all of $\mathbb{N}$
- How can a sequence of things, none of which are infinite, become an infinite thing in the limit.
- The initial part of $\{A_i | i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is entirely irrelevant. You can chop off the first $p$ sets for **any** $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and the union of the remaining sets ${A_p, A_{p+1}, A_{p+2}, ...}$ is still all of $\mathbb{N}$.

These questions don't actually express all my doubts, but hopefully you can appreciate that something fishy is going on with limits and infinity.

(I realize there aren't precisely mathematical questions, but humor me.)

Comment: The union of the family $\{\{0\},\{1\}\}$ is $\{0,1\}$.  All elements of the family have one element but their union has more than one element.  No element is all of $\{0,1\}$ but their union, somehow, mysteriously, becomes all of $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: As for how to prove that a $k$ exists such that $x \in A_k$, consider $k = x+1$; clearly $x \in A_k$.

Comment: I don't understand why you have a problem with "all the $A_i$ are finite, but their union is infinite". Unions of finite sets can be infinite. For each natural number $i$ let $B_i=\{i\}$.  Then the union of the finite sets  $B_i$ is $\Bbb N$ which is infinite. If you had a _finite_ collection of finite sets whose union was infinite, that would be surprising. But you don't.

Comment: A set isn’t a sequence. You can think of the elements as a sequence, and here, they have a natural order under inclusion that is isomorphic to ordered set $(\mathbb N,\leq),$ but this isn’t a feature of the set $\{A_i\mid i\in\mathbb N\}.$

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the low-hanging fruit.

> I don't know how to prove this, but I know that for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $x \in A_k$

This is quite trivial. Note that since $A_i = \{0, 1, ..., i\}$, we see that $i \in A_i$ for all $i$. So in particular, take $k = x$; then $x \in A_k$.

Since for all $i$, $A_i \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, it follows that $\bigcup\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. And we have just shown above that $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i$ So we have proved, as you suspected, that $\mathbb{N} = \bigcup\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i$.

On to the more philosophical question. Your philosophical question seems to be how an infinite thing can be built from finite things.

But when you "constructed" $\mathbb{N} = \bigcup\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i$, you took advantage of the full infiniteness of $\mathbb{N}$. It's right there - $\bigcup\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$.

So it shouldn't be surprising that we can build a single infinite set using an infinite number of finite sets.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n = \infty.$$
Again no $n$ is infinite but still the limit is infinite. That's just how the idea of infinity works I guess?

Infinity is an idea, an important concept; but we're not really saying it "exists" in the real world.